# NGINX won't listen on port 443

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I installed SSL on my DigitalOcean droplet following this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Inspite of this, all requests on `https://` are getting refused!

I ran the following command : `sudo netstat -anltp` and found that `NGINX` isn't listening on port `443`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1337/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2315/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1442/sshd
tcp        0    288 138.197.137.XXX:22      45.64.239.214:53476     ESTABLISHED 1590/0
tcp        0      0 138.197.137.XXX:22      218.65.30.134:65311     ESTABLISHED 2340/sshd: root [pr
tcp        0      0 138.197.137.XXX:22      45.64.239.214:53487     ESTABLISHED 1724/sshd: root@not
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2315/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1442/sshd
```

My `nginx.conf` file is shown below:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is shown below :

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-torrentic.cf.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}



# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Firewall status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

What is wrong ? How do I fix it ?

Comment: do you have the default firewall running on your droplet? run `sudo ufw status` on in your command line. what does it return?

Comment: @Minidodds - I have added `Firewall Status` to my question.

Comment: Run `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` (or whatever the errorlog is set to) while restarting nginx. Any errors regarding `443/ssl`?

Comment: No errors regarding `443/ssl`

Comment: Im assuming you followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04. If you did, run `sudo service nginx restart`. Does it throw any erros? If you didnt, go through that tutorial and make sure you didnt miss any steps

Comment: Try removing `http2` from the `listen 443...` directive and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: @alindt - That didn't make any difference!

Comment: @Minidodds - I did a redo of all the steps mentioned. Still, no resolution.

Comment: Please run `sudo nginx -t`.

Are you sure you posted the entire `nginx.conf`? Please check again, because if that's its content, nginx shouldn't start at all.

Comment: @alindt - It's the content of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: Please modify your question and post the contents of both `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` _and_ `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, making sure not to lose any lines of content. Feel free to **redact** sensitive configuration, but **don't delete** anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129745/discussion-between-alindt-and-codewalker).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to have symlinks from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/*` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`:

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
$ sudo ln -sf ../sites-available/default .
$ sudo service nginx reload
```

See [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34408592#34408592) for more details.